# Fail to add newline to separate text for the node

Tags: tikz-arrows

Here is for My LaTeX code for this diagram.
I can't add newline for the text

```
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[draw, -latex] 
\begin{tikzpicture}

% first row of nodes
\draw(1,0.5)  circle(0.5) node[align = center, label=below:{$K_1, h_1$}] {$\times$};
\draw(4,0)  rectangle (6,1)  node[pos=0.5,  label=above:{$K_2, h_2$}] {$10^{-4}$};
\draw(8,0)  rectangle (10,1) node[pos=0.5, label=below:{Displacement \\ Sensor}]{$100 \times V_S$};
\draw(12,0) rectangle (14,1) node[pos=.5, label=below:{$Amplifier$}] {$10^3$} ;



% lines for connecting nodes
% The leftest arrow
\draw[arrow] (1,1) (-2,0.5) -- (0,0.5) node [pos=0.1, draw, sloped, above right]  {Input force} node [below, pos=0.5] {F \\ Balancing force};
\draw[arrow] (1,1) (2,0.5) -- (4,0.5) node [pos=0.1, draw, sloped, above right]  {$O_1 = I_2$} node [below, pos=0.5] {$\Omega$};
\draw[arrow] (1,1) (6,0.5) -- (8,0.5) node [pos=0.1, draw, sloped, above right] {$O_2 = I_3$} node [below, pos=0.5] {$mV$};
\draw[arrow] (1,1) (10,0.5) -- (12,0.5) node [pos=0.1, draw, sloped, above right] {$O_3 = I_4$} node [below, pos=0.5] {$mV$};
% The rightest arrow
\draw[arrow] (1,1) (14,0.5) -- (16,0.5) node [pos=0.1, draw, sloped, above right] {$O_4 = O$} node [below, pos=0.5] {$Pa$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I want to display it in this way.

> Displacement
>
> Sensor

> F
>
> Balancing Sensor

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168443/234654) can help.

Comment: Not clear, what your drawing shall look like. E.g. do you want an input box, labeled "Input .. cing force", with an arrow connecting this box with the circle? Or do you want label text abaove AND below an arrow? // Also: Please. Complete. Code. For. Copy, paste and compile.

Comment: @MS-SPO Displacement Sensor should be in two separate lines

Comment: Put a separate node, like: "node at (1,1) [align=left] {first line\\secondline};".

Comment: @MS-SPO
How do you add `$\otimes$` as a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guess of what you are trying to do

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(1,0.5) circle[radius=0.5] node[label={[below=0.8cm]:$K_1, h_1$}]{$\times$};
\draw(4,0) rectangle (6,1) node[pos=0.5, label={[above=0.3cm]:$K_2, h_2$}]{$10^{-4}$};
\draw(8,0) rectangle (10,1) node[pos=0.5, label={[align=left, below=0.8cm]:Displacement\\Sensor}]{$100\times V_S$};
\draw(12,0) rectangle (14,1) node[pos=0.5, label={[below=0.8cm]:$Amplifier$}]{$10^3$} ;
\draw[-latex] (-2,0.5) --node[above]{Input force} node[below, align=left]{F\\Balancing sensor} (0,0.5);
\draw[-latex] (2,0.5) --node[above]{$O_1=I_2$} node[below]{$\Omega$} (4,0.5);
\draw[-latex] (6,0.5) --node[above]{$O_2=I_3$} node[below]{$mV$} (8,0.5);
\draw[-latex] (10,0.5) --node[above]{$O_3=I_4$} node[below]{$mV$} (12,0.5);
\draw[-latex] (14,0.5) --node[above]{$O_4=O$} node[below]{$Pa$} (16,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Horizontal commutative diagram]

Normally one would never hardcode a diagram like this with coordinates, circles and rectangles. You could use e.g. `tikzcd`

Answer (score 0):

Add `align=center` and some distance.

```
\draw(8,0)  rectangle (10,1) node[pos=0.5, label={[align=center,label distance=0.5cm] below:Displacement \\ Sensor}]{$100 \times V_S$};

\draw[arrow] (1,1) (-2,0.5) -- (0,0.5) node [pos=0.1, draw, sloped, above right]  {Input force} node [below=0.5cm, pos=0.5, align=center] {F \\ Balancing force};
```